# UITabBarControllerの全てのコントローラをアプリ起動時に読み込む方法

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

アプリ起動時のスプラッシュ画面にて、
タブバーにある全てのコントローラーを読み込むことはできるのでしょうか？

タブＡ、タブＢ、タブＣのアイテムがあったときに、それぞれのタブのViewControllerのviewDidload()を発火させたいのですが
やり方が分からず困っております。

Comment: 「アプリ起動時のスプラッシュ画面」と言うのはiOSが勝手に表示するものなので、その間に確実に何かの処理を実行すると言うことはできません。また、「それぞれのタブのViewControllerのviewDidload()を発火させたい」と言うのは一体どう言う理由によるものでしょうか? その辺をはっきりさせておかないと、なんらかの回答がついてもそれをあなたのコードに反映することは難しい、なんてことが発生して、回答者にとっても、あなたにとっても無駄な時間を費やしてしまうことにもなりかねません。また、このご質問に直接の関係はないので恐縮ですが、あなたは過去のご質問を放置しっぱなしにしているようです。「承認する」「コメントをつける」「自己回答する」など適切な形で、コメントや回答を書いてくれた人たち、質問を読んでくれた人たちになんらかのレスポンスを返すべきです。

Comment: 「承認する」という機能があることを知りませんでした。ご指摘ありがとうございます。